# Find out where program is running from?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have several Nginx installs on my server and now i cannot seem to figure out where the currently running Nginx is running from..

I have the PID which is: 12530

Can i use that to find out where Nginx is running from?

Or is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean by "running from"?

Comment: All i want to do is restart the currently running nginx, but i cannot find out how.. Stopping with /etc/init.d/nginx stop seems to stop some other server, because my pages still load in the browser

Comment: `readlink -f /proc/12530/exe`

Comment: If you want to see "the current environment folder" when the application runs, you look at the PWD of /proc/<PID>/environ file.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: wait, you've got a PID, it's not as difficult as the-below. Just look at the output of:

```
$ sudo ls -l /proc/12530/exe
```

---

If by "where Nginx is running from" you mean "which particular binary", you can use something like the following:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep nginx | grep txt
nginx  8100  root  txt  REG     202,1   7645520    1931225 /usr/sbin/nginx
...
```

..which tells me that the version at `/usr/sbin/nginx` is running.

You might need to `apt-get install lsof`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in `/proc/<PID>/`. It contains lots of information about the process and is documented in [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc). The file `exe` will be a symlink to the executable. I.e:

```
$ ls -l /proc/11806/exe 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u u 0 Feb  7 13:15 /proc/11806/exe -> /usr/bin/emacs23-x
```

PID 11806 is running the emacs23-x executable.

Answer (score 0):

How bout this?

```
lsof -p <pid> | grep txt
```